# Use template formula to multiple rows and make them work regardless of language settings?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a formula:

```
=IF(OR(AND(H6<>"";I6<>"");AND(H6="";I6=""));"Price error";IF(H6<>"";F6*H6;IF(G6<>"";G6*I6;"")))
```

I can use VBA to write

```
Range("J6") = "=IF(OR(AND(H6<>"""";I6<>"""");AND(H6="""";I6=""""));""Price error"";IF(H6<>"""";F6*H6;IF(G6<>"""";G6*I6;"""")))"
```

But what is the best approach if I want to:

- enter the formula into many rows of column J?
- make sure that the formula works regardless of language settings? For example I know that IF is called OM in the Swedish version of Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> enter the formula into many rows of column J?

you could apply formula for entire range as follows:

```
Range("J6:J100").Formula = "=IF(H6=...)"
```

in that case formula would be automatically adjusted:

- in `J6` you'd have `=IF(H6=...)`
- in `J7` you'd have `=IF(H7=...)`
- ....
- in `J100` you'd have `=IF(H100=...)`

> make sure that the formula works regardless of language settings? For
>   example I know that IF is called OM in the Swedish version of Excel

use `Range.Formula` instead `Range.FormulaLocal` and. In that case you should apply formula using "English" version (e.g. `If` instead `Om` in the Swedish) and always use comma `,` instead semicolon `;` as formula delimeter (even if your regional separator is semicolon `;`):

```
Range("J6:J100").Formula = _
    "=IF(OR(AND(H6<>"""",I6<>""""),AND(H6="""",I6="""")),""Price error"",IF(H6<>"""",F6*H6,IF(G6<>"""",G6*I6,"""")))"
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to use a template formula even if I am not setting all of the formulas at once? I want to say to VBA "Use this formula but pretend that you are on row 100 instead of row 6!"

Comment: it seems to me that the easyest way is to use `R1C1` formula style with `Range.FormulaR1C1` property. For details read [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/formulaR1C1.html) and [this](http://tduhameau.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/the-beauty-of-the-r1c1-reference-style/)